# Creating a form contact page?

Tags: pages, forms, contact

I'm newbie on WordPress, how can I create a new page/top-link/contact-form for a contact page?

I'm using a [third party theme](http://smthemes.com/demo/fashionstyle/) which allows you to create a contact form with field, but unbelievable I can't understand how to add that form to the site, or it maybe it doesn't comes up!?

Is there any way to create that from standard WP backend?

Comment: Whats the theme name please?

Comment: FashionStyle from Smthemes

Answer (score 2):

Probably the theme is using a page template. When you create a Contact page, on the right side, look for "Template" and select the Contact page template from the drop down menu.

Comment: I wouldnt say that until being certain of the theme in use. The contact form could be shortcode, not a page template.

Comment: Most likely. Either way both answers should be right.

Comment: I agree lol. However, we need to know the theme he is using. And he hasnt told us yet

Comment: FashionStyle from SMthemes dot com

Comment: Just checked your theme. Edit the page and make sure to select the "Contact form" template, right below the "Publish information".

Comment: Follow his answer and let us know if you get it set up

Comment: ok guys tomorrow i'll check that deeply ;) thx for now ;)

Comment: Badaa you're welcome. By the way it is really easy. On the page you want the contact form, before you hit "publish", look down below the publish button for "templates". It is a drop down. Choose the contact form template and then publish. Do that tomorrow and check back with us. We'll be around!